# angular2materialize compatability with angular 5 version

Tags: angular

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@5.2.11
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY materialize-css@1.0.0-rc.1
```

Getting this error while doing `npm` install for using `materialize` in **angular 5**.

In there is any way to use `angular2Materialize` in `angular 5 version`?